# ajax get json function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

i wanna to get a json file from a php page but my code doesn't work, what's wrong?

> my php page is

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$jsonstart="{'files' : [";
$jsonend="]}";
$content="{'firstname' : '".$_GET['name']."' , 'lastname' : 'izadi'}";
$jsonfile=$jsonstart.$content.$jsonend;
print $jsonfile;
```

> my ajax code is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("getfilesinfo.php?name=afshin", function(data){
         alert(); 
         var test=JSON.parse(data);
         alert("Data: " + test.files[1].firstname + "\nStatus: " + status);
     });  
});
```

Comment: You must use `json_encode(ARRAY)`

Comment: what do you get if you console data i.e. `console.log( data );` inside the getJSON() callback?

Comment: `$jsonfile` is not a valid `JSON`

Comment: `Key` and `Values` must wrap in double quotes(`"`) => `<?php
$name='Rayon';
$jsonstart='{"files" : [';
$jsonend="]}";
$content='{"firstname" : "'.$name.'" , "lastname" : "izadi"}';
$jsonfile=$jsonstart.$content.$jsonend;
print $jsonfile;
?>`

Comment: $json is not a valid json file , why?

Comment: _$json is not a valid json file , why?_ `jsonlint.com` says `Error: Parse error on line 1:
{ 'files': [{  'first
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'`

Comment: You also do not need the to parse the result into json, it is already done by `.getJSON` and this line will in fact cause js to crash `var test=JSON.parse(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use json_encode() in your php file like this.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$array = array(
    'firstname' => $_GET['name'],
    'lastname' => 'izadi'
);

echo json_encode($array);

exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this cleaner code using json_encode

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$array = array(
    'firstname' => $_GET['name'],
    'lastname' => 'izadi'
);

echo json_encode(array('files'=>array($array)));
```

js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("getfilesinfo.php?name=afshin", function(test){
         alert("Data: " + test.files[1].firstname );
     });  
});
```